# Numerically compute the product of a sum of exponentials

Tags: numerical-methods, logarithms, exponential-function

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $\beta\in[0,1]$ and $\sigma\in(0,1)$. I need to compute $$u'(x',y'):=\beta+(1-\beta)\prod_{i=1}^d\psi(y'_i-x'_i)\;\;\;\text{for }x',y'\in[0,1)^d$$ in a computer program, where $$\psi(x):=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\phi(x+k)\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R$$ and $$\phi(x):=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}\;\;\;\text{for }x\in\mathbb R.$$

> How should I do this such that I'm not suffering from floating point imprecision?

A typical choice would be $\beta=0.3$ and $\sigma=0.01$. For this choice of $\sigma$, the $k$th summand in the definition $\psi(x)$, for $x\in(-1,1)$, is extremely small when $|k|\ge2$. Is there a cleaver way to compute the product in the definition of $u'(x',y')$?

Answer (score 1):

An approach that I have used for sums with many small terms is to do it in batches, say 100 at a time and then add the batches.  I don't think the product should have a serious precision problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, at least if $\beta=0$, the product may be computed to $0$ while it should not. And regarding the batch thing: As I wrote in the question, in my example choice for $\sigma$ the sum consists only of three significant terms and the others are negligible.

Comment: If the product is getting to 0 (floating point arithmetic), you could occasionally multiply by a power of 2 (keeping track) to avoid underflow.